# Is there a bijection between the set of prime ideals of norm $~ q~$, and the set of ring maps to $~F_q~$?

Tags: ring-theory

OK, for each given ring morphism,
$\mathfrak{o}\rightarrow~F_{q}~$,
there exists another distinct arrow after composing with the Frobenius map (or a power of it).

So, if $q = p^{n}$, then there are n distinct endomorphisms $F_{q}\rightarrow F_{q}$., and hence at least $n$ distinct ring homomorphisms from $\mathfrak{o}$ to $F_{q}$.

But, from a highly technical text on etale cohomology (so I'd be inclined to believe it), the book simply says, the primes (or, prime ideals) $\mathfrak{p}$, such that,
$\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}\approx F_{q}$,  correspond bijectively to the ring maps,
$\mathfrak{o}\rightarrow F_{q}$, which given the first (?) isomorphism theorem made sense intuitively.

However, to get a grasp on this, I tried an example,
$\mathbb{Z}_{3} [x]$ as my ring $\mathfrak{o}$, the three prime ideals,
$(x^2+1), (x^2+x+2),$ and $(x^2+2x+2) =\mathfrak{p}$, so then I obtained the isomorphisms, $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p} \approx F_{9}$, but I instead find SIX ring maps $\mathfrak{o} \rightarrow F_9$!
The three given from the three prime ideals, and their composition with the non trivia Frobenius map.

So finally, my question:
Are the sets bijective "up to endomorphism", where the maps are paired in an equivalence relation, or am I missing something?

I have four books on abstract algebra, and naturally each isomorphism yields an ideal as the kernel, like I said I'm getting 6 not just 3 maps, and can't find any reference on such a bijective correspondence.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Prime ideals of norm $q$ are in bijection with surjections $R \to \mathbb{F}_q$, **up to** postcomposition with Frobenius, for exactly the reason you state. I don't know whether your text has a typo or whether you have misread it, but it is not true that prime ideals of norm $q$ are in bijection with surjections $R \to \mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: David Speyer thanks for your answer. And for some reason I can't enter a new line without it posting so forgive the lack of indentations. I also didn't realize I even received an answer until I decided to refresh page, thinking opening my browser refreshed for me. But you're saying, ignore the extra Frobenius maps and just going by the direct canonical maps, a bijective exists? But if you include ALL maps including Frobenius, they're not bijective, just to clarify?

Comment: Or rather I should say, the bijectuon occurs if you count the endomorphisms together, to clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand your phrasing. Let's take an example. Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ of Gaussian integers. There is exactly one ideal of index $9$: The ideal generated by $3$. There are two maps from $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ to the field with $9$ elements. Namely, there are two square roots of $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_9$, call them $\pm j$. We can send $a+bi$ either to $(a \bmod 3) + (b \bmod 3) j$ or to $(a \bmod 3) - (b \bmod 3) j$. These two maps are related to each other by post composition with Frobenius: If you apply one map and then apply Frobenius, you get the other map.

Comment: Does this clear up your question?

Comment: Yes I believe so. So count one map and it's composition with Frobenius into one "class", so that one class is in bijection with the number of such ideals, as you said there is exactly one such ideal (in this case of order 9).

Comment: Yeah like you said in your first reply, bijective up to, that would tend to make sense. Take the class of each map and its composition with all powers of Frobenius, then each class is bijective with each surjection from R to the relevant field of order q, again thanks.